# How to ignore inherited super() keyword when asserting object equality

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class called MyObject which inherits fields from a parent class MyParent. In my testing, I have two instances of these objects I would like to assert are equal. All of their fields are equal except, for their super field inherited from MyParent.

```
MyObject a -> MyObject(super=MyParent(field1="123", field2=...), myobjectfield1="blah")

MyObject b -> MyObject(super=MyParent(field1="456", field2=...), myobjectfield1="blah")
```

I have tried the following assertion approach to try and exclude super but, with no luck :(

```
assertTrue(new ReflectionEquals(a, "super").matches(b));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but why would you need to assert child objects are equal if their parent fields are _not_ equal?

Comment: @AlexRudenko The fields are getting set automatically in a separate background process. Also, I don't have any form of a setter that can alter these fields for the MyObject objects

Comment: You just write an `equals()` method that doesn't call superclass methods. Unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @user207421 Do you have an example of an equals() method that doesn't call a super() method?

Comment: I didn't say anything about `suoer()` methods. The suggestion I have made is trivially obvious and doesn't require an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a comparator to check equality ignoring parent class.

let's create a utility to match a field. (assuming all have getters)

```
public static <T> boolean match(String field, T first, T second) {
   try {
      PropertyDescriptor descriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(field, first.getClass());
      Method method = descriptor.getReadMethod();

     return Objects.equals(method.invoke(first), method.invoke(second));
   } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return false;
}
```

Now, let's create a comparator,

```
Comparator<MyObject> comparator = (first, second) -> {
  boolean status = Arrays.stream(MyObject.class.getDeclaredFields())
  .map(Field::getName)
  .allMatch(field -> match(field, first, second));

  return status ? 0 : 1
}
```

And we can use that assertion

```
assertTrue(comparator.compare(expected, actual) == 0)
```

Comment: Say I have 200 fields on MyObject. Now I need to explicity compare the attributes from objects 'first' & 'second'. Yes, this could work but, would not be a simply ideal solution.

Comment: @user3696953 Added one small utility to verify fields. hope that helps. :)